# Aws Lamda returns null - the same code in Node returns the value

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  var data = "api-key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = true;

  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
      callback(null, this.responseText);
    }
  });

  xhr.open("GET", "https://the-url");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("apikey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xhr.send(data)

};
```

I am trying to call an API in AWS Lambda but it returns Null, I have the same code in node js and it works fine, but in the LAMBDA no matter where I place the callback() it  just return "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `async` from the function.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
```